# How to add Duration to LocalDateTime for API level lower than 26

Tags: java, android, datetime, duration

I am developing an application for API level 19 (KitKat).

I have a `LocalDateTime` object and a `Duration` object. I need to add this `Duration` to `LocalDateTime`.

Android Studio shows that `plus(TemporalAmount)` method of `LocalDateTime` class is avaliable since API level 26 which is Oreo and it supports less than 1% of devices right now.

How can I do it with API level 19?

Comment: The whole `LocalDateTime` class should only be there for API 26, so you need to use another means of time anyway for API 19.

Comment: What do you recommend deekay ?

Comment: You can use the ThreeTen Backport: http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/ You'll also need ThreeTenABP: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP And there's a tutorial here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project But you'll need to change your imports to use the backport's classes (from `java.time` to `org.threeten.bp`).

Answer (score 8):

Currently you can enable `java.time` in lower level apis by upgrading grade to 4.0.0. [read more here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring).

Comment: this is a great answer, saved me so much time, thank you

Answer (score 3):

**For Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.0+:**

Use Java Desugaring feature so you can use Java 8 Date library without any problem for API level lower than 26 too. For more details [read this](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring)

**Old answer:**

The *bbb* answer in the comments is correct.

Currently the best option for android is [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). Jake Wharton explains why it's better to use this library rather than Joda-Time and ThreeTenBP in Android.